# How can I store the result of and if else statement to use on another page of an android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm looking to store the result of a stopwatch timer when I click the stop button, then place this result in a table on the second page of my an android app.  The stopwatch works as planned, but how to I store the result?

```
mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!running) {
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
            chronometer.start();
            running = true;
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            chronometer.stop();
            running = false;
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have the value which you want to send to another page?

Comment: I want the current time of the chronometer to be stored on the second click(else in the code) of the button. So what ever time is being shown when paused.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass your data through the `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("STOP_WATCH_TIME", "8:03"); // Pass whatever data you want.
startActivity(intent);
```

And then within your `ResultActivity`, you can get that data.

```
String time = getIntent().getStringExtra("STOP_WATCH_TIME");
```